# composition of continuous and uniformly continuous functions

Tags: calculus

I have a fundamental question. Let  $\,f:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous and $\,g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be uniformly continuous functions. Can  $\,g\circ f$ be uniformly continuous?

Comment: It certainly can be. If $f$ is also uniformly continuous (so that it will also be continuous) then the composition will be as well. Further, for any continuous (or otherwise) function, if $g$ is any constant function on $Y$ then the composition will be uniformly continuous. Did you mean to put in some more restrictions?

Comment: no, here only g is uniformly contious f is just continous.

Comment: I think you want to ask if $gf$ can be not uniformly continious

Comment: @banx Please reread the comments and solutions carefully. We think you just made a minor misstatement, but we think we know what you intended to ask.

Comment: I think a question that might be harder: Let $g,f$ be continuous but not uniformly continuous. Can $gf$ be uniformly continuous ?

Comment: @Amr What about $f=\exp$ and $g=\ln$?

Comment: @Amr: That question is easy. Just make sure that $gf$ is zero everywhere, for instance by making $f$ zero on $(-\infty,0)$ and $g$ zero on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @TonyK: $gf$ is probably intended by Amr to represent function composition. It's fairly common notation, but can lead to some confusion.

Comment: @Cameron: I didn't think of that! But the question is still easy: just make sure that $g$ is constant on the range of $f$. For instance, $f(x) = x^2; g(x) = 0$ if $x \ge 0$, and $x^2$ if $x < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be, but it need not be. If $g$ is a constant function, then it certainly will be, for example. On the other hand, if $Y=Z$ and $g$ is the identity function, then $g\circ f=f$, so we can find easy counterexamples, there.

Answer (score 1):

If you really meant to ask "Is it possible for $g\circ f$ to be not uniformly continuous?", then let $f$ be your favorite continuous-but-not-uniformly-continuous function, and let $g$ be the identity function. The composition is clearly not uniformly continuous.

As I mentioned in the comments, the composition of uniformly continuous functions is continuous, so if you really meant your original question, then *yes*, it *is possible*, because it is possible that $f$ is uniformly continuous as well.

Comment: I think you mean $gf$ is not uniformly continonus not discontionus

Comment: @amr ahh yes, of course :) Thanks This is what I meant from the beginning, as you can tell from my example :/

Comment: @rschwieb You're right, I rushed through your answer and didn't realise you answered something different than what the OP asked.

Comment: @GitGud That's OK: I'm always open to input, and glad to have someone reading.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a fundamental question. Let f:X→Y be continuous and g:Y→Z be uniformly continuous functions. Can g∘f be uniformly continuous?

Certainly. If $f:X\to Y$ happens to be uniformly continuous itself, then $g\circ f$ is uniformly continuous.